# Confusion using SimpleJSON - JSON interpretor

Tags: c#, php, json

I'm using SimpleJSON which can be found [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON). <-- Source and documentation.

Here's the JSON that's being output in my PHP script using the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

```
{
    "response":3,
    "establishments":[
        ["1","-107.102180","39.410870","0"], 
        ["8","-106.977715","39.377403","7.03707478751404"],
        ["9","-106.843636","39.484631","14.706647410396497"],
        ["12","-106.950661","39.230804","14.846070600598637"]
    ]
}
```

In the examples on the SimpleJSON page, "establishments" should technically be a nested object, and not a nested array. After going through the code I had assumed that the following would suffice

```
int id = N["establishments"][0].Value
double long = N["establishments"][1].Value
double lat = N["establishments"][2].Value
```

Where N is the node containing the Json Information (more info in docs).

However all of these values are returning blank, could anyone point out why? So far arrays have been my only problem with this, and I don't understand the logic behind this enough to figure out what's wrong on my own.

**NOTE:** As pointed out by @jskidie this is a two dimensional array, I'm having problems returning the full Array (in the 2nd dimension) not the values.

Comment: What is the value of `N`?

Comment: As per the link to SimpleJson, N is the Node generated containing the JSON data. - I'll edit the question

Comment: Edited question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have multi dimensional array. Try:

`int id = N["establishments"][0][0].Value
double long = N["establishments"][0][1].Value
double lat = N["establishments"][0][2].Value`

Comment: Oops, you're correct here, but the issue is that I can't return the full array. I should fix the question. -- I need to return the array (The one that contains the other arrays) so I can iterate over them.

Comment: Can you provide an example of result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was stored in the JSONArray class.

```
 JSONArray array = json["establishments"].AsArray;
 for(int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++) {
 }
```

which allows me to iterate over all occurrences.